# Can't test app on iPhone after updating iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode

I ran it fine, did all the certification hassle and my sister updates the iPhone and next day I can't test anything, Xcode doesn't simply recognize the damn iPhone. Please help. There is literally nothing I have found that solves this problem..

I should say that it worked fine a day ago. I'm so damn angry and frustrated I can't type..

Apple does a really really poor job of being clear what to do.

EDIT: I also see this "You don’t have permission to save the file “iOS DeviceSupport” in the folder “Xcode”."

Comment: Has Xcode (well, technically the iOS SDK) been updated to handle the version of iOS the iPhone now has?  What have you tried so far?  Where did you see the error message about permissions?

Comment: I see the error message when I plug in the iPhone to the Macbook Pro laptop. I go to Xcode and click Organizer and then I click 'Devices'
There I see my iPhone and on the right hand side is where I see the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Xcode do you have and what iOS-version does the test-device have?

To test applications with Xcode 4.2.1, the device has to be of iOS 5.0.1 or down. If you updated to the iOS 5.1 beta, you will need to download Xcode 4.3 beta as well, as Xcode 4.2.1 does not have the required DeviceSupport-files for the beta.

EDIT:
Since you have Xcode 4.2, you will need to update to 4.2.1 to be able to test your applications on an iOS 5.0.1-device.

Comment: Please see updated answer, you will need to update to the most recent Xcode-version, 4.2.1.

Comment: Ah, that sucks.. However, it should work when you get it installed! :)

Comment: How do I get it installed lol. Is it a free dl? Is it possible, since my macbook pro is a Snow Leopard.. am I required to waste $1000.00 + for a new mac?

Comment: Do you have Mac OS X 10.6? If so, you will need to update to Lion via [Mac App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/no/app/os-x-lion/id444303913?l=nb&mt=12). If you don't have Mac App Store, or the link doesn't work, your mac may not be able to run Lion. See this link for more info: http://www.apple.com/macosx/specs.html

Comment: Thank you. It Works, I am now downloading OSX Lion 10.7.2.. then it should work. God damn apple.. At least it was $29.99 and not $100.00 +

Answer (score 1):

You'll need Xcode 4.2.1 if your iPhone is version 5.0.1.

Comment: Yeah I know, but to install 4.2.1 I need Mac OSX version 10.7 or higher. My MacBook Pro is 10.6.8 ..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, 
Here is my solution!

First Update both Xcode and phone with the latest software.
Then go to the organizer and enable iPhone for development.
Done ..

Comment: This question has already had an answer accepted, and yours is a great deal vaguer than that answer.